# Библиотеки для реализации БПФ

Tags: c++, c, fft

Подскажите библиотеки С/С++ для реализации быстрого преобразования Фурье.

Comment: Вы ведь уже искали, нашли их и они вас чем-то не устроили? Приведите список неустроивших чтобы вам их еще раз не советовали.

Comment: Искал только в Google. Но я не работал ни с одной из них, не знаю, какие у них достоинства/недостатки.

Comment: Тогда зачем вы просите искать за вас еще раз, если вы уже сами нашли?

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/fft_multiply например :)

Comment: http://fftw.org/

Answer (score 2):

Быстрых реализаций алгоритма ДПФ огромное множество. Практически все они рассматривают исходный массив как многомерный и решают проблему посредством перестановок и одномерных БПФ малой размерности.

Общеизвестный алгоритм является частным случаем алгоритма Кули-Тьюки для массивов с размерностью степени двойки, хотя в более общем случае он рассчитан на произведение малых чисел.

Возможность использования того или иного множителя в размерности преобразования Фурье определяется наличием соответствующего "малого" БПФ (известны для **N = 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 16**), которые получили название алгоритмов Винограда. Особенность "малых" алгоритмов - в возможности их представления с помощью 1) набора предсложений, 2) перемножения компонент полученного вектора на фиксированные коэффициенты и 3) набора постсложений. Это резко снижает количество умножений.

Приведёнными идеями реализации БПФ не ограничиваются. В частности, один из самых быстрых алгоритмов (Нуссбаумера-Квендалла) для размерности **1008 = 7*9*16** использует [китайскую теорему об остатках](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85) и имеет структуру, аналогичную малому БПФ.

Если тема интересна всерьёз и надолго, можно порекомендовать книгу [Р.Блейхута](http://www.toroid.ru/bleihutR.html).